# Netsuite seems to hijack almost all keyboard input

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

Before you think you know what the problem is, let me explain it to you. I have scoured the internet for an answer to this and I cannot get a straight answer as to what is happening.

My workplace started using Oracle Netsuite as our POS software. Works great. Up until about a year or so ago. The problem I am having is, even on my home computer, the keyboard will randomly stop accepting letters, numbers, and symbols. The odd part is, modifiers such as <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>win</kbd>, <kbd>Fx</kbd>-keys, etc all continue to work. For example, when this happens, I have no problems hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and closing literally everything.

Most pages I see are referencing to a JavaScript hijacking keystrokes in the browsers, however this completely hijacks the keyboard in windows as well as every other application. This occurs both at home and on my work PC. At work, turning my 2nd monitor (which has the keyboard and mouse connected to it's rear USB ports) off and back on, instantly solves the problem. However, no matter how many times I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> reboot my K55 and unplug the keyboard as well as reboot windows completely, I cannot get keyboard access again until I open Netsuite using the on-screen keyboard with the mouse and click inside of the text box for the login window. Sometimes, I even have to login and click inside the Global Search box and click out of it for it to work again. Mind you, I don't use Netsuite at home for any reason, except now to get access to my keyboard back that is.

I am literally pulling my hair out over this crap and I don't know what could be causing this to happen. It sometimes doesn't happen for several weeks, other days it occurs multiple times a day.

Anyone have an ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event someone comes across this, I've discovered that it is not Netsuite that is hijacking the keyboard input. It is either HTML5, CSS, or a flaw in the browsers. If you click into certain text boxes and then switch to a new tab, there is a chance your keyboard input will not work until you click outside that box.

For example, I logged into Proxmox and switched to a new tab to open another page and discovered it wouldn't type. I clicked back to Proxmox, clicked into the Search box (also done in Netsuite) and then clicked outside the search box and then switched tabs and viola! The keyboard works.